# Android Studio Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException i am trying to fit decodeYUV420SPtoRGB class with mlkit

Tags: java, android-studio, image-processing, indexoutofboundsexception, firebase-mlkit

```
public abstract class ImageProcessing {

    public static final int A = 0;
    public static final int R = 1;
    public static final int G = 2;
    public static final int B = 3;

    public static final int H = 0;
    public static final int S = 1;
    public static final int L = 2;

    private ImageProcessing() {
    }




    public static int[] decodeYUV420SPtoRGB(byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
        if (yuv420sp == null) throw new NullPointerException();

        final int frameSize = width * height;
       /* Log.d("frames", String.valueOf(frameSize));*/
        int[] rgb = new int[frameSize-1];

        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height-1; j++) {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width-1, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width-1; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & (yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;
                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                }
                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0) r = 0;
                else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
                if (g < 0) g = 0;
                else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
                if (b < 0) b = 0;
                else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            }
        }
        return rgb;
    }



    public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bmp, int degrees) {
        if (bmp == null) throw new NullPointerException();

        // getting scales of the image
        int width = bmp.getWidth();
        int height = bmp.getHeight();

        // Creating a Matrix and rotating it to 90 degrees
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degrees);

        // Getting the rotated Bitmap
        Bitmap rotatedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rotatedBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        return rotatedBmp;
    }


    public static byte[] rotate(byte[] data, int degrees) {
        if (data == null) throw new NullPointerException();

        // Convert the byte data into a Bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        // Getting the rotated Bitmap
        Bitmap rotatedBmp = rotate(bmp, degrees);

        // Get the byte array from the Bitmap
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rotatedBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
}




private static final class DetectionThread extends Thread
  {

    private byte[] data;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public DetectionThread(byte[] data, int width, int height)
    {
      this.data = data;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      if (!processing.compareAndSet(false, true)) return;
      try
      {

        int[] img = null;

        img = ImageProcessing.decodeYUV420SPtoRGB(data, width-1, height-1);
        Log.d("usmankhan", "detected");
```

when this thread is called in CameraPreviewCallback it gives error .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException i am student i don't know how to resolve it. as i am newbie to android and student.
i will be very thankfull if anyone can help me out?

i want to detect movement as well as running this firebase.mlkit landmarks to detect face.

Comment: I did it the issue was that i wasn't actually giving correct parameters for the width and height. with this I resolved the issue "  Camera.Size size = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();"

Comment: Improved formatting